# Chrome blue border around images on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I've strange blue borders around images on google chrome see for your self

[image: Google chrome Example]
[image: Other Example]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I disabled Chrome Hardware Acceleration and that **Solved** the problem for me.

### Steps

1. Enter `chrome://settings` in the address bar at the top of Chrome. Or, use the menu button at the top right of the browser to choose **Settings**.
2. Scroll to the very bottom of that page and choose the **Advanced** link.
3. Now scroll to the very bottom of that page of settings to find some other options.
4. Under the "System" heading, locate and disable the **Use hardware acceleration when available** option.
5. If you're told to **relaunch** Chrome, go ahead and do that by exiting any open tabs and then opening Chrome again.
6. **(OPTIONAL)** When Chrome starts up, open `chrome://gpu` again and check that the words **"Hardware accelerated"** doesn't appear next to most of the items in the **"Graphics Feature Status"** heading