# Google chrome color patches around transparent images.

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version. The PNG images are not displaying correctly in my Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.84 (Official Build) (64-bit).

***See the facebook icons***

[image]

***Google Logo***

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome blue border around images on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061141/chrome-blue-border-around-images-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

**solution:** 
**in chrome://flags/** find **Force color profile** and set on **sRGB**